# How to send and receive packets to remote server using UDP in Python?

Tags: python, udp

I am trying to send and receive UDP packets in python 3 using the simple code below. However, this does not seem to work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? My program works internally on my machine, but will not receive packets from a remote server. It should work with this server and port number : 35.185.116.250:8000.

Another test server is 35.185.116.250:8001

Moreover, I feel like the line that may be causing problems is: clientSock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), listening_port_number))

I am working on Windows.

```
import socket

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
#the next line (which is commented out)works when I run my program and contact a server on my own machine
#clientSock.bind(("",listening_port_number))
my_host_IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

#the following does not work for receiving packets from a remote server
clientSock.bind((my_host_IP, 8001))

def send_packets():
    address = '35.185.116.250'
    port = 8000
    clientSock.sendto(my_host_IP.encode('utf-8'),(address,port))
    print("Sending packet to address and port number: %s %s"%(address,port))
    modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSock.recvfrom(2048)
    print(modifiedMessage.decode())

send_packets()
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall? Maybe the specific port is locked (on linux ports are locked by default, I think)

Comment: I am working on Windows and I'm on a public network.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy you need to add an exception for the address you want acces, and you can do it or in your code or in your network interface